# TypeError: object of type 'HTTPConnection' has no len() in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, streamlit

I am trying to make a web scraping application with streamlit framework, but getting the below error while writing the below code, can anyone suggest how to resolve it.

```
url = st.text_input('www.example_abc.com') # type of this is .txt
connected = http.client.HTTPConnection(url) # converting type to http.client.HTTPResponse

TypeError: object of type 'HTTPConnection' has no len()
 page_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
```

In python, we can work out with the below code:

```
import urllib.request as url
url.urlopen("www.abc.com")
```

I required the type as “http.client.HTTPResponse”

Code I have written:

```
import bs4 as bs
import streamlit as st

source_txt = st.text_input("") #Input url will be entered, say: https://rgtnt.com/
st.write(source_txt)

import http
source = http.client.HTTPConnection(source_txt)

page_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Can you provide the necessary code to reproduce your error, i.e. library imports and example url?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have updated the post with the code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the much simpler requests package to fetch from the HTTP source? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: I am using streamlit, so I get the url type as text, how to convert text to HTTP request?